# Trying to add new work item type "Feedback Request" in ADO cloud version but it states it is already in use

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I need to add the work item "Feedback Request" to my project in Azure Dev Ops(cloud version).

When I try and add it I get the error " VS403066: The work item type name Feedback Request you specified is already in use. Choose a different name and try again."

I do not see it in my work item types and can not find it in any other area(see attached image).
Is it hidden somewhere?

I need to add the field "ReflectedWorkItemId" to the "Feedback Request" work item. If I can't add this work item it has to be somewhere? How would I get to it to add a field to it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Feedback Request" is a hidden predefined work item type. You can start using it: [Get feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/feedback/get-feedback?view=azure-devops)

1. Add "Other links" control to the dashboard:

[image]

2. Use Request feedback

[image]

Comment: I was able to add the widget. 

Now I can not figure out how to access the "Feedback Request" work item  to add a field to it? 
 I am also getting the same "already in use" error for these work items - Code Review Request, Code Review Response, Shared Parameter and Shared Steps. 

I need access to those also so I can add a field to them.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: would you be able to look at this issue I have with migrating a Work Item as you are very knowledgeable in this area:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800302/original-tfs-description-work-item-field-type-is-html-destination-is-text-how

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not supported to customize "Feedback Request" work item type or those work items you mentioned in azure devops.

You can create **FeedbackRequest** work item directly from work items like **Epic**, **Feature**, **Product backlog items**, See below screenshot.

Go to the workitem **edit page** and click the **3dots**-->**Request feedback**

[image]

After the request feedback is created. It will be automatically linked as the child work item to the work item.

[image]

If you create Feed backRequest work item from the widget. You can manually type the ReflectedWorkItemId to its **Description** or **Title** fields.

[image]

Then you can create [Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/titles-ids-descriptions?view=azure-devops) to query the Feed backRequest with **description** or **title** filter. See below example:

[image]

**Code Review Request** work item is avaiable in Team Foundation version control (TFVC) repository. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=azure-devops) for more information.

Shared Parameter and Shared Steps are available in Test Case work item

[image]

[image]

However, you can also [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=21) to support customizing these work item types.

Comment: So from what you are saying is that I can not add fields to Code Review Request, Code Review Response, Shared Parameter and Shared Steps? It looks like you are showing screenshots from another version of ADO. I can not find the work item edit page in the cloud version of ADO.
What I am ultimately trying to do is migrate data from a server version to the cloud version and the tool I am using required the Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId field in the work items that I want to migrate over.

Comment: No, i am afraid you cannot add fields to these workitems. Can you try mappipng the `ReflectedWorkItemId` to `System.Tags` as workaround? so that the ReflectedWorkItemId will be reflected on the Tags.